# Noob Question - Why does my screen look like this?

Tags: 3d-view

Hey Blender Community,

I have a noob question. It's very hard to google my specific question because I seem to lack the correct terminologies to things.

Here is the question. When following a tutorial online, I realized that my render viewport looks all greyed out- not sure if this is the right terminology. From the tutorial, I'm noticing that the backdrop is darker than the file I have opened.

Here is an image of what my screen is looking like.

[image]

Here is what another file looks like. As you notice, the background is a "darker grey"

[image]

Comment: Looks like you are in a view port shading mode and your light is off

Comment: @fowl Hey thanks for mentioning the light! But it's strange. the background seems to be in a light grey appearance. I've uploaded another file that seems to have a darker backdrop which helps the shadow reach its darker value. Please let me know if any of you know a solution to this problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the *World* > **Surface** configuration:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try each of these 4 viewport shadings, and the drop down menu will change according to the mode. From left to right: Wireframe, Solid, Material preview, and Rendered (means the scene will look close to what it will look like when you render them).

[image: Viewport shading]

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! I did each of those but taking a second look at the file, it seems like I might have pressed something in to make the whole background and the viewport into a lighter grey. I've attached another photo of a new file. The new file looks to have a darker grey BG. I'm noticing that this might be the reason why everything is appearing to be lighter grey.